# Code to change the text table Color in all the Slides

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint

I want a macro that loops through all the slides and change the text in a table to black. When I try the code below, I get the error message: `Method 'Table' of 'Shape' failed`.

This is my code:

```
Sub TableAllBlack()

Dim lRaw As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape

With ActivePresentation
    For Each oSl In .Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            Set oTbl = oSh.Table
                With oTbl
                    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                            For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                                With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                                            TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End With
                            Next
                    Next
                End With
            Next
        Next
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not every shape has a Table associated with it.  Just add the statement `If oSh.HasTable Then...` And it should work

This `If` statement should be placed to encapsulate all of the Table calls, so place it directly before the `Set oTbl = oSh.Table` line

Comment: Thank you for ypur answer! i still have one mistake in the line: TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0). It always comes Object required! what should i do? Thanks

Comment: @Zigouma Add a period before TextFrame